how to delay substitution of $* in Makefile?
I'm trying to abstract a make prefix repeated 9 times:
BUILD_CMD      := @make O=$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$* \
                      BR2_EXTERNAL=$(PROJECT_DIR) \
                      -C $(PROJECT_DIR)/buildroot

and an example target:
%-source: %-config ccache-dir dl-dir
        $(BUILD_CMD) source

Problem is $* substitution happens too early (effectively null) so the output directory is incorrect when make bcm2836-build is invoked.
How can I delay the substitution of $* until the target is evaluated?
I tried to escape \$\* but this didn't work.

The solution to defer variable substitution in a Makefile is to use a define statement:
define BUILD_CMD
        @make O=$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$* \
                BR2_EXTERNAL=$(PROJECT_DIR) \
                -C $(PROJECT_DIR)/buildroot
endef

make then substitutes $* for % when you call your target(s):
%-build-cmd:
        @echo $(BUILD_CMD)
.
.
.
%-source: %-config ccache-dir dl-dir
        $(BUILD_CMD) source
%-build: %-config ccache-dir dl-dir
        $(BUILD_CMD) $(CMD)

I am not certain if this is buildroot specific syntax as I was inspired by thumbing through section 16.2 (The .mk file) of The Buildroot user manual.
This is a top level Makefile (not .mk) and it works so hope this is helpful to someone else as it is a very powerful abstraction construct to tidy up Makefiles!
